# c# project-wide using alias directives

Tags: c#

C# has a feature called [Using alias directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). They allows you do make an alias of a type like this:

```
using CustomerId = MyComp.MyProject.Core.EntityKey<Customer, int>;
```

This feature however only works on a per-file basis. I'm looking for a way -any way- to do this project-wide or even solution-wide.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to remove the verbosity of writing things like `EntityKey<Customer, int>`, `EntityKey<Order, long>`, etc. I like to prevent having to define those aliasses in each file. The `EntityKey<TEntity, TKey>` is a `struct`, so I can't create derived classes.

Answer (score 9):

No, that does not exist. Aliases are strictly per-file.

Answer (score 0):

As of C# version 10, there is a "global using" language feature you could use.